# Finding the number of items in a list that are not duplicated

Tags: list, performance, duplicates, unique

I have a list of fruits and there are some duplicates in the list. I am not after the unique items in the list nor the count of the number of unique items. If I wanted thsoe details I would simply use a set.

I want to instead calculate the number of fruits in the list that are not duplicates i.e lemon,orange,tomato,passionfruit = 4

Here's my code which works ok but is slow as it uses nested loops.

```
fruits=['apple','pear','pear','apple','strawberry','lemon','orange','strawberry','tomato','passionfruit']

fruits_len=len(fruits)

uniq=0

for loop1 in range(0,fruits_len):
    
    flag=0
    for loop2 in range (0,fruits_len):
        
        if loop1==loop2:
            continue
       
        if fruits[loop1]==fruits[loop2]:
            flag=1
            break

    if flag==0:
        uniq+=1

print(f'There are {uniq} fruits not duplicated in the fruits list  ')
```

The code yields the following correct result.

```
runfile('C:/A/untitled0.py', wdir='C:/A')
There are 4 fruits not duplicated in the fruits list
```

The only problem is that on much larger lists my code would be slow.I want to resolve the above in the most efficient way possible. I tried to devise a solution using list comprehension but its awkward because the two nested loops have code in between them.

How can I make my code run much faster? (bragging rights to he/she who can come up with the fastest solution)

Thanks Peter

Answer (score 0):

You could use a dict to store the counts of the elements from the array and select the elements that have only one occurrance

```
fruits=['apple','pear','pear','apple','strawberry','lemon','orange','strawberry','tomato','passionfruit']

histogram = {}

for item in fruits:
  if item not in histogram:
    histogram[item] = 1
  else:
    histogram[item] += 1

print(len([ i for i in histogram if histogram[i] == 1]))
```

Outputs

```
4
```

Time

```
CPU times: user 2 µs, sys: 1 µs, total: 3 µs
Wall time: 6.2 µs
```